# Page contents going inside another div that sits on footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, footer

Contents of the page are going inside another div that sits on the top of footer. Can someone please help me know how to make a fixed div to sits on top of the footer and the contents of the page should be scrollable

```
<body>
    <header class="container-fluid">
    </header>
    <div id="fixWidth">
        <h1>hi how are u</h1>
        <h1>hi how are u</h1>
        <h1>hi how are u</h1>
        <h1>hi how are u</h1>
        <h1>hi how are u</h1>
        <h1>hi how are u</h1>
        <h1>hi how are u</h1>
        <h1>hi how are u</h1><h1>hi how are u</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="footer navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <h4>This part of content Content should be fixed</h4>
        </div>
      <footer class="container-fluid">
            <div class="content">
                 <p>@copyright</p>
             </div>
      </footer>
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you provide some css or a jsfiddle?

Comment: I didn't get your question((

Answer (score 0):

if u want any div to,be fixed just assign a fixed height..and the div due to which the fixed layout,is changed..add a style attribute to the div and add propery scroll to be scroll.then when the div has more elements than its height then a scroll will appear which will help u to fixed your layout..hope u get ur answer..